# How to hide completely a map in OpenLayers?

Tags: gis, openlayers

I made an OpenLayers map, which has several WMS and WMTS layers.
Of course, I can hide an HTML element of the OpenLayers map by changing the "display" style.
But I noticed that data fetching still happens for each layer.
So what is the elegant way to hide a map in OpenLayers?

PS: I do not want to change the "visible" property of each layer into "false".

Thank you.

Comment: You could remove the map from the element as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/teleport.html (the new target could be null or undefined, or not appended to the document)

Comment: thank you! 

olMap.setTarget(null);

Answer (score 0):

olMap.setTarget(null);

Thank you, Mike!